# Why is this website "wenda.io" branching all Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: discussion, support, copycat-sites

Today I was I was doing a Google search for a programming related query and in results I got the exact same Question heading on [*wenda.io*](http://www.wenda.io) too, along with `stackoverflow.com` and when I just typed the URL I saw it has almost all questions from Stack Overflow with different *look and feel* (not just the top voted ones).

Why is this website "forking" all questions of our `stackoverflow.com`?

I have seen popular websites like [*ISO C++*](https://isocpp.org/) grab questions from `stackoverflow.com` but only the Selected Recent C++ Questions.

Comment: As to why such sites do this? They are trying to create a site that attracts users so they can earn money from advertisements.

Comment: Thanks, well this seems annoying when google search results on first top five from this website

Comment: Absolutely, and Google actually has procedures to report such sites. Reporting the site to Stack Exchange through the procedure we linked you to makes them aware of the site and they'll take it from there.